# Why is 'index' equaling 0 in the routerLink, but 1 in the string interpolation?

Tags: angular, api, routes, string-interpolation

```
<form class="mt-3 mb-5" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
    <p class="mb-0 mt-1" id="invalidEmail" *ngIf="!emailValid">Invalid Email</p>
    <input class="mb-0 mt-1" type="email" id="email" name="email" ngModel required email><br>
    <button 
        (click)="getDataFromAPI()" 
        class="btn btn-primary mt-2" 
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="!f.valid"
        [routerLink]="['/profile', index]">Login</button>
</form>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">
        Featured
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{ rEmail }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Index: {{ index }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm;

  data:Array<any>;
  data2:Array<any>;
  index: number = 0;

  constructor(private JSONPlaceholder: JSONPlaceholderService) {
    this.data = new Array<any>();
    this.data2 = new Array<any>();
  }
  
  getDataFromAPI(){ 
      this.JSONPlaceholder.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.data2.push(data[i].email);
      }
      if(!this.data2.includes(this.rEmail)) {
        this.emailValid = false;
      } else {
        this.index = this.data2.indexOf(this.rEmail);
      }
    })
  }

}
```

When I click on the button, the page will go to 'http://localhost:4200/profile/0' but when without the router link, the string interpolation will have 'index' equal 1.

[image: This is the page url when I click on the button]

[image: If I have the data show on the same page, the 'index' will equal 1]

The 'index' value should equal 1. Because that is that the variable is being set to. However in the routerLink, 'index' is remaining at 0. Why won't the number change? Clearly the change is being reflected at the list group below the form, but the routerLink is not going to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This executes:

`[routerLink]="['/profile', index]`

Before:

`(click)="getDataFromAPI()"`

So this is why you get a correct index on the page and a wrong number in the route.

Simply remove `[routerLink]` and just `this.router.navigate(['/profile', this.index]` after the index has been updated to be the correct one.